# React multiple instances of same component are getting same state

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a React Component and I am creating 2 copies of it. However, when the state of 1 of them is updated, it updates the 2nd one too. I am not sure what is causing this.

Here is my code:

This is the place where I am using 2 components:

```
{this.state.selectedTab === 0 ?
    <Carousel
       size={1}
       cultureInfo={this.state.cultureInfo}
       collaboratorError={this.state.activeCollaborationError}
       getPinnedError={this.state.getPinnedUsersError}
       pinActionError={this.state.isPinnedServerError}
       user={this.state.activeCollaboratorContactsData}
       isPinnedTab={false}
       startDate={this.state.startDate}
       isMapped={this.state.isMapped}
       resetPosition={this.state.resetCollabCarousel}
       isVisible={this.state.selectedTab === 0 }
/>
:
<Carousel
  size={1}
  cultureInfo={this.state.cultureInfo}
  collaboratorError={this.state.activeCollaborationError}
  getPinnedError={this.state.getPinnedUsersError}
  pinActionError={this.state.isPinnedServerError}
  user={this.state.pinnedUsers}
  isPinnedTab={true}
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  isMapped={this.state.isMapped}
  resetPosition={this.state.resetPinnedCarousel}
  isVisible={this.state.selectedTab === 1}
/>
}
```

Here is the Carousel Code:

```
interface ICarouselProps {
 size: number;
 cultureInfo: CultureInfo;
 collaboratorError: Error.DataLayerError;
 getPinnedError: Error.DataLayerError;
 pinActionError: Error.DataLayerError;
 user: ActiveCollaboratorContact[];
 isPinnedTab: boolean;
 startDate: Date;
 isMapped: boolean;
 resetPosition: boolean;
 isVisible: boolean;
}

interface ICarouselState {
 position: number;
 width: number;
 isActiveNext: boolean;
 isActivePrev: boolean;
 isActive: number;
 }

 const numSlides = 2;
 const width = 100;
 const move = width / numSlides;
 const max = width - move;
 const min = -max;

 const numOfCards = 4;

 export default class Carousel extends BaseComponent<ICarouselProps,     

      ICarouselState> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.resetState();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: ICarouselProps): void {
    if (newProps && newProps.resetPosition) {
        this.resetState();
    }
}

doRender(): React.ReactElement<{}> {
    let wrapperWidth: number;
    let widthStyle: string;
    wrapperWidth = (this.state as ICarouselState).width;

    const style:  React.CSSProperties = {
        WebkitTransform: "translateX(" + this.state.position + "%)",
        transform: "translateX(" + this.state.position + "%)",
        MozTransform: "translateX(" + this.state.position + "%)",
        msTransform: "translateX(" + this.state.position + "%)",
        OTransform: "translateX(" + this.state.position + "%)",
        width: wrapperWidth + "%"
    } as React.CSSProperties;
    const slideWidth:  React.CSSProperties = {width: move + "%"} as React.CSSProperties;
    let nextIsDisabled: boolean;
    let prevIsDisabled: boolean;
    let slideActive: string;

    widthStyle = (this.props.size === 0) ? styles.vCard : styles.hCard;
    nextIsDisabled = !this.state.isActiveNext;
    prevIsDisabled = !this.state.isActivePrev;
    slideActive = "slideActive" + this.state.isActive;

        const totalUsers = this.props.user.length;
        const articles: JSX.Element[] = [];


        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            const cards: JSX.Element[] = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < numOfCards; j++) {
                const userIndex = i * numOfCards + j;
                if (userIndex < totalUsers) {
                    const card: JSX.Element = <Card
                        cultureInfo={this.props.cultureInfo}
                        user={this.props.user[userIndex]}
                        startDate={this.props.startDate}
                        extraMargin={userIndex % numOfCards === 0}
                    />;
                    cards.push(card);
                }
            }
            const article: JSX.Element =
                    <article className={styles.slideSingle}
                            tabIndex={0}
                            style={slideWidth}>
                        {cards}
                    </article>;
            articles.push(article);
        }
        return this.props.isVisible ?
                <div>
                    <div className={widthStyle + " " + styles.carousel + " " + slideActive} tabIndex={-1} id="Carousel">
                        <div className={styles.slideWrapper}
                            style={style}>
                            {articles}
                        </div>
                        <nav className={styles.nav}>
                            <ul className={styles.arrows}>
                                <li className={styles.stepLeft}>
                                <a disabled={prevIsDisabled} aria-disabled={prevIsDisabled} className={styles.previous} href="#"
                                    tabIndex={0}
                                    onClick = {this.prevSlideClicked}>
                                    BUTTONPREVTEXT
                                </a>
                                </li>
                                <li className={styles.stepRight}>
                                <a disabled={nextIsDisabled} aria-disabled={nextIsDisabled} className={styles.next} href="#"
                                    tabIndex={0}
                                    onClick = {this.nextSlideClicked}>BUTTONNEXTTEXT
                                </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
               </div> :
               null;

};

private resetState(): void {
    const newState: ICarouselState = {
            position: 0,
            width: numSlides * 100,
            isActiveNext: true,
            isActivePrev: false,
            isActive: 0
        };

    if (this.state) {
        this.setState(newState);
    } else {
        this.state = newState;
    }
}

private nextSlideClicked: () => void = () => {
    if (this.state.position > min + move) {
        this.setState({
            position: this.state.position - move,
            width: numSlides * 100,
            isActiveNext: true,
            isActivePrev: true,
            isActive: Math.abs((this.state.position - move) / move)
        });
    } else if ((this.state as ICarouselState).position > min) {
        this.setState({
            position: this.state.position - move,
            width: numSlides * 100,
            isActiveNext: false,
            isActivePrev: true,
            isActive: Math.abs((this.state.position - move) / move)
        });
    }
};

private prevSlideClicked: () => void = () => {
    if (this.state.position < 0 - move) {
        this.setState({
            position: this.state.position + move,
            width: numSlides * 100,
            isActiveNext: true,
            isActivePrev: true,
            isActive: Math.abs((this.state.position + move) / move)
        });
    } else if (this.state.position < 0) {
        this.setState({
            position: this.state.position + move,
            width: numSlides * 100,
            isActiveNext: true,
            isActivePrev: false,
            isActive: Math.abs((this.state.position + move) / move)
        });
    }
};

private getCarouselName(): CarouselNames {
    return "name"
}
```

};

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please post the code for the `Carousel` component?

Comment: Why you use `this.state = newState;`? This can cause weird behaviour...:  _NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable._ (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

Comment: I set this.state because this call is from the Constructor, where this.state is not initialized.

Comment: Those two carousels can't exist at the same time (thus `isVisible` is redundant), how can you say they're  'getting the same state'? If possible, strip your component(s) down to just the relevant parts and post the whole thing in your question.

Comment: I know they are getting the same state set, because when I click the next button on one, the 2nd's position is also set to that value. That is when the condition for 2nd's visibility becomes true, it shows the same position as the other one instead of a fresh position.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: hi - I added the Carousel code here yesterday, any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: @Programmer, Have you got any solution on this?

Comment: I do not think so, but somehow we moved on :)

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem.  I set a distinct 'key' property on each instance and the problem went away.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem! I knew about the key for when we render multiple elements using map() as it complains in the console. But if you use just manually paste 2 components that use state inside the state is not reset unless you add a key.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the same component for a different route (`react-router`) then you have to set `key` property for each route.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

For this kind of situation where you want to use the same component multiple times, you have to set `key` property. Otherwise, each component will have the same state.